# A (probably trivial) consequence of Dirichlet's theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) says that for any two *positive coprime* integers $a$ and $d$,
the arithmetic progression $a,a+d,a+2d,a+3d,\ldots$ contains infinitely many prime numbers.
In other word, there are infinitely many prime numbers of the form $a+nd$.

> What can be said if $a$ is negative (and $d$ is still positive)?

In particular, if $a=-1$ (for which it seems to be known that the answer is positive, namely, there exist infinitely many prime numbers of the form $-1+nd$).

$a$ and $d$ are still assumed to be coprime, since otherwise there is no chance to obtain primes of the form $a+nd$, because we have: $a+nd=
\gcd(a,d)\tilde{a}+n\gcd(a,d)\tilde{d}=\gcd(a,d)(\tilde{a}+n\tilde{d})$; notice that this shows that there are infinitely many primes $P$ such that $a+nd$ equals $\gcd(a,d)P$.

Thank you very much!

**Edit:** Robin Chapman mentions the case $a=-1$ in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32624/special-cases-of-dirichlets-theorem), but there is no explanation there, only a reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $a$ is negative, you can write $a+nd = (a+kd)+(n-k)d$ where $kd>-a$, which gives an equivalent statement with positive integers. In other words, the sign of $a$ is unimportant. $d$ needs to be positive so that there are infinitely many positive terms in the sequence in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the arithmetic progression
$$x_n = -100 + 3n$$
Note $n \leq 33 \implies x_n < 0 \implies x_n \not\in \mathbb{P}$

But at $n = 34, x_n = 2$. A subsequence $y$ of $x$ can be defined as:

$$\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}^*, y_n = 2 + 3n = x_{n+34}$$

So $y_n$ contains an infinite number of primes (by Dirichlet), therefore so does $x_n$

Now lets consider the general case:

$$\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}^-, d \in \mathbb{N}, n \in \mathbb{Z}^*,$$
\begin{align}
\text{Let }  s_n &= a + nd\\
\exists a' \in \mathbb{N} \text{ s.t. } a &= -a'\text{ (existence of additive inverse)}\\
\exists i \in \mathbb{N} \text{ s.t. } i &> a' \text{ (infinitude of the natural numbers)}\\
id &\geq i > a' \text{ (looser than necessary for simplicity)}\\
t_n &= s_{n+i} = (a+id) + nd\\
&\text{with }t_n\text{ of the required form }\square\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like your example of considering the sub-sequence which starts from the positive term (which is essentially what Chappers did; your example clarifies this).

Comment: (Please change $t_n=x_{n+i}$ to $t_n=s_{n+i}$).